# MS SQL SERVER Link Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to create link server in **Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )** to **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3)**

The link creates successfully but when i try to open the db of my new link server or select a data from link server it returns these error.

> ```
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "CSBILL" returned message "Unspecified error".
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "CSBILL" returned message "General error".
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "CSBILL" returned message "Unable to open a logical session".
> Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
> SMux Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is CSBILL accessible via ping?

Comment: I don't think `SQLNCLI11` is valid for 2008.  I think you need to use `SQLNCLI`:   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188718(v=sql.105).aspx